# Odd behaviour of Python tokenizer when parsing integer numbers

Tags: python, parsing, numbers, integer, token

I noticed the following fact with CPython3 and Pypy3, contrasting with the behaviour of both CPython2 and Pypy2:

In Python3, it looks like leading zeros when parsing code yield an error *except for a very single number which is 0*. Thus `00` is valid but not `042`.

In Python2, leading zeros are allowed for all integers. Thus `00` and `042` are valid.

Why did Python change its behaviour between both versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3 standardized how all integer literals (other than base 10) were defined: `0?dddd...`, where `?` is a single letter indicating the base, and each `d` is interpreted as a digit in the appropriate base. `0...` was retained as an exception, since 0 is 0 in any base, and was accepted as such before explicit base specifiers were required.

The biggest change related to this is that a number with a leading zero but no explicit base specifier is no longer assumed to be an octal number. Python 2 accepts both `042` and `0o42` as octal representations of decimal 34. (Early in Python's history, there were only three valid literals, with hexadecimal being the only one with a specifier. `0o...` and `0b...` were both later additions